# Spark Dataframe Scala: add new columns by some conditions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I revised my question so that it is easier to understand.

original df looks like this:

```
+---+----------+-------+----+------+
| id|tim       |price  | qty|qtyChg|
+---+----------+-------+----+------+
|  1| 31951.509|  0.370|   1|     1|
|  2| 31951.515|145.380| 100|   100|
|  3| 31951.519|149.370| 100|   100|
|  4| 31951.520|144.370| 100|   100|
|  5| 31951.520|119.370|   5|     5|
|  6| 31951.520|149.370| 300|   200|
|  7| 31951.521|149.370| 400|   100|
|  8| 31951.522|149.370| 410|    10|
|  9| 31951.522|149.870|  50|    50|
| 10| 31951.522|109.370|  50|    50|
| 11| 31951.522|144.370| 400|   300|
| 12| 31951.524|149.370| 610|   200|
| 13| 31951.526|135.130|  22|    22|
| 14| 31951.527|149.370| 750|   140|
| 15| 31951.528| 89.370| 100|   100|
| 16| 31951.528|145.870|  50|    50|
| 17| 31951.528|139.370| 100|   100|
| 18| 31951.531|144.370| 410|    10|
| 19| 31951.531|149.370| 769|    19|
| 20| 31951.538|149.370| 869|   100|
| 21| 31951.538|144.880| 200|   200|
| 22| 31951.541|139.370| 221|   121|
| 23| 31951.542|149.370|1199|   330|
| 24| 31951.542|139.370| 236|    15|
| 25| 31951.542|144.370| 510|   100|
| 26| 31951.543|146.250|  50|    50|
| 27| 31951.543|143.820| 100|   100|
| 28| 31951.543|139.370| 381|   145|
| 29| 31951.544|149.370|1266|    67|
| 30| 31951.544|150.000|  50|    50|
| 31| 31951.544|137.870| 300|   300|
| 32| 31951.544|140.470|  10|    10|
| 33| 31951.545|150.000|  53|     3|
| 34| 31951.545|140.000|  25|    25|
| 35| 31951.545|148.310|   8|     8|
| 36| 31951.547|149.000|  20|    20|
| 37| 31951.549|143.820| 102|     2|
| 38| 31951.549|150.110|  75|    75|
+---+----------+-------+----+------+
```

then I run the code

```
val ww = Window.partitionBy().orderBy($"tim") 

val step1 = df.withColumn("sequence",sort_array(collect_set(col("price")).over(ww),asc=false))
.withColumn("top1price",col("sequence").getItem(0))
.withColumn("top2price",col("sequence").getItem(1))
.drop("sequence")
```

The new dataframe looks like this:

```
+---+---------+-------+----+------+---------+---------+
| id|      tim|  price| qty|qtyChg|top1price|top2price|
+---+---------+-------+----+------+---------+---------+
|  1|31951.509|  0.370|   1|     1|    0.370|     null|
|  2|31951.515|145.380| 100|   100|  145.380|    0.370|
|  3|31951.519|149.370| 100|   100|  149.370|  145.380|
|  4|31951.520|149.370| 300|   200|  149.370|  145.380|
|  5|31951.520|144.370| 100|   100|  149.370|  145.380|
|  6|31951.520|119.370|   5|     5|  149.370|  145.380|
|  7|31951.521|149.370| 400|   100|  149.370|  145.380|
|  8|31951.522|109.370|  50|    50|  149.870|  149.370|
|  9|31951.522|144.370| 400|   300|  149.870|  149.370|
| 10|31951.522|149.870|  50|    50|  149.870|  149.370|
| 11|31951.522|149.370| 410|    10|  149.870|  149.370|
| 12|31951.524|149.370| 610|   200|  149.870|  149.370|
| 13|31951.526|135.130|  22|    22|  149.870|  149.370|
| 14|31951.527|149.370| 750|   140|  149.870|  149.370|
| 15|31951.528| 89.370| 100|   100|  149.870|  149.370|
| 16|31951.528|139.370| 100|   100|  149.870|  149.370|
| 17|31951.528|145.870|  50|    50|  149.870|  149.370|
| 18|31951.531|144.370| 410|    10|  149.870|  149.370|
| 19|31951.531|149.370| 769|    19|  149.870|  149.370|
| 20|31951.538|144.880| 200|   200|  149.870|  149.370|
| 21|31951.538|149.370| 869|   100|  149.870|  149.370|
| 22|31951.541|139.370| 221|   121|  149.870|  149.370|
| 23|31951.542|144.370| 510|   100|  149.870|  149.370|
| 24|31951.542|139.370| 236|    15|  149.870|  149.370|
| 25|31951.542|149.370|1199|   330|  149.870|  149.370|
| 26|31951.543|139.370| 381|   145|  149.870|  149.370|
| 27|31951.543|143.820| 100|   100|  149.870|  149.370|
| 28|31951.543|146.250|  50|    50|  149.870|  149.370|
| 29|31951.544|140.470|  10|    10|  150.000|  149.870|
| 30|31951.544|137.870| 300|   300|  150.000|  149.870|
| 31|31951.544|150.000|  50|    50|  150.000|  149.870|
| 32|31951.544|149.370|1266|    67|  150.000|  149.870|
| 33|31951.545|140.000|  25|    25|  150.000|  149.870|
| 34|31951.545|150.000|  53|     3|  150.000|  149.870|
| 35|31951.545|148.310|   8|     8|  150.000|  149.870|
| 36|31951.547|149.000|  20|    20|  150.000|  149.870|
| 37|31951.549|150.110|  75|    75|  150.110|  150.000|
| 38|31951.549|143.820| 102|     2|  150.110|  150.000|
+---+---------+-------+----+------+---------+---------+
```

I am hoping to get two new columns top1priceQty, top2priceQty which store the most updated corresponding qty of top1price and top2price.

For example, in row 6, top1price= 149.370, based on this value, I want to get its corresponding qty which is 400(not 100 or 300). in row 33, when top1price=150.00000000, I want to get its corresponding qty which is 53 that comes from row 32, not 50 from row 28. same rule apply to top2price

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You were very close to the answer by yourself. Instead of collecting set of just one column, collect array of 'LMTPRICE' and it's corresponding 'qty'. Then use getItem(0).getItem(0) for top1price and getItem(0).getItem(1) for top1priceQty. To keep the order by INTEREST_TIME for getting correct qty, use INTEREST_TIME  also after 'LMTPRICE' and before 'qty'.

```
df.withColumn("sequence",sort_array(collect_set(array("LMTPRICE","INTEREST_TIME","qty")).over(ww),asc=false)).withColumn("top1price",col("sequence").getItem(0).getItem(0)).withColumn("top1priceQty",col("sequence").getItem(0).getItem(2).cast("int")).drop("sequence").show(false)

+-----+-------------+--------+---+------+---------+------------+
|index|INTEREST_TIME|LMTPRICE|qty|qtyChg|top1price|top1priceQty|
+-----+-------------+--------+---+------+---------+------------+
|0    |31951.509    |0.37    |1  |1     |0.37     |1           |
|1    |31951.515    |145.38  |100|100   |145.38   |100         |
|2    |31951.519    |149.37  |100|100   |149.37   |100         |
|3    |31951.52     |119.37  |5  |5     |149.37   |300         |
|4    |31951.52     |144.37  |100|100   |149.37   |300         |
|5    |31951.52     |149.37  |300|200   |149.37   |300         |
|6    |31951.521    |149.37  |400|100   |149.37   |400         |
|7    |31951.522    |149.87  |50 |50    |149.87   |50          |
|8    |31951.522    |149.37  |410|10    |149.87   |50          |
|9    |31951.522    |109.37  |50 |50    |149.87   |50          |
|10   |31951.522    |144.37  |400|300   |149.87   |50          |
|11   |31951.524    |149.87  |610|200   |149.87   |610         |
|12   |31951.526    |135.13  |22 |22    |149.87   |610         |
|13   |31951.527    |149.37  |750|140   |149.87   |610         |
|14   |31951.528    |139.37  |100|100   |149.87   |610         |
|15   |31951.528    |145.87  |50 |50    |149.87   |610         |
|16   |31951.528    |89.37   |100|100   |149.87   |610         |
|17   |31951.531    |144.37  |410|10    |149.87   |610         |
|18   |31951.531    |149.37  |769|19    |149.87   |610         |
|19   |31951.538    |149.37  |869|100   |149.87   |610         |
+-----+-------------+--------+---+------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Hi Parvez, thank you for helping me out. There's one issue with this code. Using `sort_array(collect_set(array("LMTPRICE","qty")).over(ww)` I am losing time information.  For example, if in time 31951, `LMTPRICE` is 120,qty is 50, in  time 31952, `LMTPRICE` is still 120, qty is 40. In time 31972, `top1price` is 120, according to your code, it will return qty 50, but I am looking for 40. Do you know how to properly solve the issue?

Comment: How about updating Window: val ww = Window.partitionBy($"INTEREST_TIME").orderBy($"INTEREST_TIME")

Comment: in that case, the collected array is based on the same INTEREST_TIME in that raw. it didn't solve the original problem. I am revising my question, maybe it is easier for you to understand the question now

Comment: Hi Quency, updated my answer. To give precedence to INTEREST_TIME for getting correct qty, added it to the collected set after price and before qty.

Comment: Thank you Parvez! Do you know how to get top2priceQty?